# $C^{k,\alpha}$ dependence of ODE solutions on initial data

Tags: fractional-calculus, cauchy-problem

I faced such a question. Consider the Cauchy problem for an ODE:
$$
\begin{cases}
y'=F(t,y)\\ y(0)=y_0.
\end{cases}
$$ Assume $F$ has the regularity $C^{k,\alpha}$ (i.e. it has partial derivatives of order up to $k$, and these derivatives are $\alpha$-Hölder). Can one conclude that the solution function also has the  $C^{k,\alpha}$ dependence on $t$ and the initial data $y_0$?
For nonzero $\alpha$ I couldn't find it in the literature.
Thanks!

Comment: For $k=1$ it seems a routine work (but always a work) since we know the expression for the differential of the general solution $\eta(t, x)$ in terms of $dF$, which is a  composition of   maps between various function spaces. 
The case $k>1$ I think should follow by induction.

Answer (score 1):

There are some papers that discuss the $C^{k,\alpha}$ dependence of solutions to ODEs or related systems. For example, [this paper](https://mathinmoscow.org/wp-content/uploads/ODES21parameter-dependence.pdf) shows the continuous dependence of solutions to algebraic differential systems on the initial data, using the concept of $C^{k,\alpha}$-smoothness.

[This other paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3103/S1063454114040025) studies the dependence of the maximal interval of existence of solutions to a nonlinear differential equation on the initial data, assuming that the right-hand side is $C^{k,\alpha}$-smooth.

Perhaps you can try to generalize the results from the papers I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I think you might run into uniqueness problems here. For example, if we consider the ODE $y' = \sqrt{|y|}$, with $y(0) = y_0$, then this has the solution

$$
\hat{y}(t)= ( t^2 + 2 \sqrt{y_0} )^2/4
$$

But also, if $y_0 =0$, then there is another solution given by simply $ \tilde{y} (t) = 0 $.

Since we have two solutions for the same initial data, it seems that you'd have an infinite Holder constant if you try to compare the $\hat{y}$ solutions to the $\tilde{y}$ solutions.

Comment: Note that this only happens for k=0. For k greater or equal than 1, F is Lipschitz, which is enough to ensure continuity.